# Why are all my minecraft updates deleting?

Tags: xbox-360, minecraft-legacy-console

Whenever I sign into my Xbox Live account on my Xbox 360, all of the updates I previously installed have been deleted and I have to reinstall a 570mb update which takes an hour. How can I fix it so that it stops deleting updates?

Answer (score -2):

I have a guess, but for this to work I might need you to have a hard drive.

Maybe the reason it keeps uninstalling is because you might not have enough space on the hard drive, or locally on your console, so what it does is it takes it and saves it locally to your Wi-Fi until it is in needed so it deletes it when it is being unused.

Another idea (this is weird of why it might be doing this but I have no idea why it would be doing this either) is that it is storing the update in the RAM so whenever you turn off the console, it dumps the RAM deleting the update. But even if that is the case, I would try and fix it and NOT keep my console on all the time; because even though it might be rare with certain console versions that doesn't mean it could still happen. It could red ring of death if you leave it on for too long, so don't go trying it.